# Sprocket touching the biggest cog no matter B screw...how do I fix?

Tags: shimano, derailleur, derailleur-rear

My Shimano rear derailleur was destroyed, for some reason got into the rear wheel, so I had to buy a new one. Hanger was a little misaligned but I think I fixed it.

I bought the new derailleur, changed cable and housing, the chain was pretty new.

All installed, checked L and H, and I noticed the derailleur was a little close to the cogs. but worked fine in all the 6 smaller cogs.

When I try to go into the biggest cog, no matter the B screw, the sprocket is touching the cogs (with the chain in between) making a weird noise and sometimes it cannot even get up there.

The first derailleur was a Shimano TY500 6-7 speed. I ordered another one, a Shimano Tourney RD-TY300 6/7-Speed  but is doing the same thing!

The rear cassette has a biggest cog of 34T

I'm running out of options... only I can think is replacing the hanger to see if that is the issue.
[image: rear cassette]

[image: rear derailleur]

Comment: Show some pics please.

Comment: Closeups of the the B screw showing the hanger might help.

Comment: By "sprocket" do you mean the jockey wheel?

Comment: a) the derailleur should pivot freely around the bolt that attaches it to the hanger - does it in your case? b) it may happen that the chain is a bit too long and does not move the cage "counterclockwise enough" - try to move the cage by hand like you would like to loosen the chain. c) if all fails, hanger extender (enough listings on ebay) can be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the TY-300 and TY-500 are rated for a large/low sprocket of 28T to 34T so they are both within spec.   There are no other variants, only the -SGS long cage is available.

https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney/RD-TY300-SGS.html

https://bike.shimano.com/en-AU/product/component/tourney/RD-TY500-SGS.html

---

I'd strongly suggest checking the the hanger alignment before spending more money on replacement parts.

You need a bolt that fits the hanger (possibly salvage this from your old destroyed unit) and a longish flat rigid bar, and something to measure down to the rim.

[image][image]

The measurement of the offset to the rim needs to be as accurate as you can, but within 10mm at the rim should be adequate.

---

The other option is that your B screw is damaged, bent, not pushing hard enough, or the stop is broken/damaged/missing.  A clear and well-lit photo of your frame and hanger would help show if this is the problem.

Comment: I didn't think about the hanger being bent - would also explain why the orginal derailuer " got into the rear wheel,", so its likely to happen again unless the hander is straightened.

Comment: The stop for the B screw may be broken or bent so that the B screw doesn't even touch the stop.

Comment: Hi! thanks for all the answers! the B screw should be ok as i tried with 2 new derailleurs. with sprocket I was trying to say the jockey wheel :) I think the alignment of the hanger is the issue. will check that further! Sorry for an additional question... how do i post a picture?

Comment: @LucasMartinez the B screw stop may be damaged - that's the part of the frame or hanger where the B screw presses.   You can add a photo to your question using the [edit](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/posts/68187/edit)  link

Comment: It was the hanger alignment! Thanks @Criggie now it's working beautifully!